# How to change the default line style for every plotly figure in a r file

Tags: r, plotly

I am writing a paper which will require several figures with multiple lines in each.  I want to have all of the figures formatted the same.  For example: all lines should be 2pt and my first line is blue and solid, second is red and dashed, third is green and dotted, etc. Currently, I am setting all of these properties manually in every figure (as shown below).  Is there a more efficient way to do this for a large number of figures? Can I change plotly's default line style? I haven't seen anything related to this issue except the colorway command. Thanks in advance!

Example code:

```
library(plotly)
x <- c(0,1,2)
y1 <- c(0,1,2)
y2 <- c(2,3,4)
y3 <- c(4,3,2)
figData <- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3)
fig1 <- plot_ly(figData, x=~x, y=~y1, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
         line = list(color = rgb(.04,.27,.66), width = 2)) %>%
add_trace(y=~y2, line = list(color = rgb(.78,.04,.08), width = 2,dash="dash"))
fig1
fig2 <- plot_ly(figData, x=~x, y=~y2, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
         line = list(color = rgb(.04,.27,.66), width = 2)) %>%
add_trace(y=~y3, line = list(color = rgb(.78,.04,.08), width = 2,dash="dash"))
fig2
```

I know that matplotlib has this capability using something like:

```
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=["b", "r", "g"])
```

so I was wondering if plotly had something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create an object that contains the details for the similar lines and reference those within the plotly codes.  If you want to make changes to those lines, just adjust the values in `line1` or `line2` and it will apply to anywhere you call for that line type.

```
library(plotly)
x <- c(0,1,2)
y1 <- c(0,1,2)
y2 <- c(2,3,4)
y3 <- c(4,3,2)

line1 <- list(color = rgb(.04,.27,.66), width = 2)
line2 <- list(color = rgb(.78,.04,.08), width = 2,dash="dash")

figData <- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3)

fig1 <- plot_ly(figData, x=~x, y=~y1, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
                line = line1) %>%
  add_trace(y=~y2, line = line2)


fig2 <- plot_ly(figData, x=~x, y=~y2, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
                line = line1) %>%
  add_trace(y=~y3, line = line2)

fig2
```